# Does Spring Data support Elasticsearch 5.x?

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data

Does the latest version of Spring Data (2.1.0.RELEASE or 3.0.0M1) support Elasticsearch 5.x? If not, When will it support it?

There is no information about this in their docs: [Spring Data Elasticsearch](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/)

Comment: See here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/wiki/Spring-Data-Elasticsearch---Spring-Boot---version-matrix TLDR: it does not

Comment: @Strelok Thanks a lot. Any idea in which version they will support it?

Comment: You may follow progress/discussion: [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-285) and [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/pull/170).

Answer (score 4):

Not support yet, you can try ES native java api.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, now spring-data supports Elasticsearch v5.x. It's not supported with RELEASE version, it's supported with BUILD-SNAPSHOT version. To use it, you have to add repository URL as well. For maven project, build script will look something like-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>

<repository>
  <id>spring-libs-snapshot</id>
  <name>Spring Snapshot Repository</name>
  <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
</repository>
```

For detail information, you can visit https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch

**N.B. While writing this answer, latest version of elasticsearch and spring-data-elasticsearch was 5.4.2 and 3.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT respectively. Those two were compatible.**

Comment: Support for 6.0?

Comment: Yes, spring data elasticsearch supports ES6.
Spring data elasticsearch v3.1.x and v3.2.x support ES v6.2.2 and v6.5.0 respectively. For more information please visit https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch#maven-configuration