# Elasticsearch 5 and spring data Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to connect to Elasticsearch 5 using spring data Elasticsearch.

As per the link -  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch ,spring data elastic search - 3.0.0.M4 is compatible with Elasticsearch 5.4.0

But I am getting the below error while trying to connect to Elasticsearch

```
Exception in thread "main" NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{ERkAnVs8Rn2Vp_kkJFwOWA}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}]]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:348)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:246)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportProxyClient.execute(TransportProxyClient.java:59)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.doExecute(TransportClient.java:366)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:408)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:397)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient$IndicesAdmin.execute(AbstractClient.java:1250)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient$IndicesAdmin.exists(AbstractClient.java:1272)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate.indexExists(ElasticsearchTemplate.java:630)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate.createIndexIfNotCreated(ElasticsearchTemplate.java:911)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate.createIndex(ElasticsearchTemplate.java:164)
    at com.javacodegeeks.spring.elasticsearch.LearnElasticSearch.loadData(LearnElasticSearch.java:84)
    at com.javacodegeeks.spring.elasticsearch.LearnElasticSearch.main(LearnElasticSearch.java:38)
```

Let me know if any of you could successfully connect to Elasticsearch 5 or above version using spring data Elasticsearch.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42001828/does-spring-data-support-elasticsearch-5-x Similar to this , can get help from this reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked fine with the below versions:

Elastic Search - 5.5.0
Spring Data Elastic Search - 3.0.0.RC2

Answer (score 0):

You may try to define node in elasticsearch -> elasticsearch.yaml -> node.name

Resolved for us